# How to Aceess cell level ComboBox in WPF DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, combobox

My data grid column template which has combo box in it is as below  .

```
<my:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="dgColReferece" Header="References"  >
     <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <ComboBox x:Name="cmbReferece_SRV" Loaded="cmbReferece_SRV_Loaded" Width="160" SelectionChanged="cmbReferece_SRV_SelectionChanged"
                                                      IsTextSearchEnabled="True" SelectedValue="{Binding Reference,  Mode=TwoWay}" >
              </ComboBox>
          </DataTemplate>
     </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

All combo boxes have Add new as one item in them which has value -2. When the user clicks on add new a new item added to the database and should be rebound to all comboboxes in the grid.

Below is my code behind for `SelectionChanged`

```
private void cmbReferece_SRV_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {  ComboBox objComboBox = (ComboBox)sender;

      if (objComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString() == "<-- Add New -->")
      {
           //code for  saving new item entered by user to database

           if (IsSaved)
           {
               DataSet dsReference = (DataSet)GetFStdReference();

               CommonCalls.BindDropDownList(cmbReferece_SRV, dsReference.Tables[0], "Reference", "Reference");
           }

           objComboBox.SelectedValue = -1;

       }

   }
```

This will bind the new item only to the combobox in the selected row. But I need it to bind to all comboboxes? How Can I do this. I am new to wpf and binding stuffs  > How can i Proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

You code above is a little confusing. Can you explain more what are you trying to do. I can see several deviations from the proper WPF programming practises esp. regarding using comboboxes in datagrid.

E.g.

1. Why are you using events like `cmbReferece_SRV_SelectionChanged` and not using `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath` via `Converter`?
2. Also what is your `ComboBox.ItemsSource`? DataTable? List of objects?
3. Why are you setting `ItemsSource` of a `ComboBox` in its own `SelectionChanged` event, which is counterproductive.

I understand that you are new to WPF, so may be if you explain your problem to me, I can suggest some useful WPF practises of coding for your issue.

Comment: combo box item source is datatable  . i am rebinding because once he selects the item "Add new" a new item gets added to the db . that code part is not shown here bu i mentioned it .so after adding a new item i am again i am rebinding the daasource to reflect added new item in the combo box